# Sql Server ODBC Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, odbc

I'm trying to create a linked server in SQL server 2017, linked system is odbc (criteria criOdbc)

**Test 1 Form SQL Server SSMS**

```
select * from OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DSN=criteria64;uid=xxxx;pwd=yyyy;','select * from table where key<10')
```

-->  Give this error "Error converting data type DBTYPE_DBDATE to date."

**Test 2 Form SQL Server SSMS**

```
select * from OPENROWSET('MSDASQL','DSN=criteria64;uid=xxxx;pwd=yyyy;','select key from table where key<10')
```

--> Works perfectly

**Test 3 In c# (load form odbc then bulk insert in sql server)**

```
OdbcConnection acc = new OdbcConnection("DSN=criteria64;uid=xxxx;pwd=yyyy;")
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("select * from table where key<10", acc);
....
```

--> Works perfectly

**Test 4 connect the same table in MS Access as linked table**

--> Works perfectly

**Conclusion**

- Msdasql (Provider OLE DB Microsoft for ODBC) --> Doesn't work well with date and some other type .net
- System.Data.Odbc (.NET Framework
  Data Provider for ODBC) --> Works perfectly

**Final question**

Is possible to use NET Framework Data Provider for ODBC in linked server? (cant find any documentation)

If not

Is there any kind of connector (odbc based) tath I can try to use in linked server in alternative to "msdasql" ?

**Note**
Casting every single date colum using a case statement is not a solution for me. I'm searching for a global fix.

I also need to Write into this tables.

My more comfortable alternative in this case is use c#.

_

Thank you for your time

Comment: Have you tried a different ODBC driver?

Comment: No, is a very rare system , only one odbc driver